# Which "approximate" value of f(0.98) is this question looking for?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, logarithms, approximation

In a section of a calculus workbook dealing with local linearity and linear approximations of functions, the following question is posed:

Consider the function f(x) = aln(x+2). Given that f'(1) = a/3, what is the *approximate* value of f(0.98)?

(A) (a/3)*(-0.02) + aln(2.98)

(B) -0.02a/3

(C) (0.98)*ln(a/3)

(D) (a/3)*a*ln(2.98) + 0.98

(E) (a/3)*0.98 + aln(2.98)

When I look for an equation of a line tangent to f(x) at x=1, I get y=(a/3)(x-1) + aln3. Plugging in x=0.98, I get (a/3)(-0.02) + aln3, which seems to correspond to none of the answer choices . . .

(A) seems the closest, and therefore would give an "approximate" value, but if they're using the slope (a/3) why are they not then using the y-value at that the point (1, aln3) with that slope, which is f(1) = aln(1+2) = 3?

If we say x = 1 and x' = 0.98, then the formula they seem to be using to approximate f(x') is f(x')≈f'(x)(x'-x) + f(x') which seems sort of silly, because it assumes we already know what f(x'), in which case, why would we be looking for it? The way I learned to do it is f(x')≈f'(x)(x'-x) + f(x).

Comment: right, then if f(x) is f(1) = aln3, why is there no answer choice that corresponds with your formula (which is also the one I wrote in the last paragraph of the question ^^)？

Comment: Please see [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset your math correctly.

Comment: Indeed, your workbook seems to be wrong

Comment: The answer is 
a Log[3] + 1/3 a ( 0.98-1) 
because we use the formula at x=1 and
f(x°) is about f(1) + f'(1)(x-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll redo everything,
just to make sure that
you are correct.

If
$f(x) 
=a\ln(x+2)
$,
$f'(x)
=\frac{a}{x+2}
$.
So,
$f'(1)
=\frac{a}{3}
$.
 This is therefore
a *consequence* of
the definition of
$f(x)$,
so I do not see why 
it is "given".

Anyway,
for a nicely behaved function
(which this one is),
$f(x+h)
\approx f(x)+hf'(x)
$.
Putting
$x=1$ and $h=-.02$,
$f(0.98)
\approx f(1)-0.02 f'(1)
= a\ln(3)-0.02\frac{a}{3}
= a(\ln(3)-\frac{0.02}{3})
$
so I agree with your answer.

My guess:
The person creating the answers
saw the
"$\ln(3)$"
and thought it to be
"$\ln(1)$",
which is zero.
This would make
the final result
$-0.02 a/3$,
which is answer 
(B).

Comment: Ahh thanks for that suggestion as to what could have happened at the end, that would make sense